# Using play's interactive console while auto compiling not loading changes

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, typesafe, typesafe-activator

I'm new to scala and play framework and so far I find them awesome. However I was wondering if there was a way to automatically load changes in the REPL after compiling.

What I want to achieve is something like an interpreted language, where after changing the file you get the changes in. Now I have to re-import my controller to get my changes.

Thanks

Comment: Pretty sure running `console` forks it's own VM, so re-compiling wouldn't affect it--similar to the way the application is reloaded in dev mode, the whole server is restarted.

Comment: I haven't played with play yet, but I bet some variant of :replay would work.  If not, a ticket might receive some attention for that use case.

Comment: So bottom line is not possible?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it, short of hacking sbt/Scala REPL. `:replay` only seems to work in a single REPL session, and once restarted is lost.